# Page not found 404 Django?

Tags: python, django, http, url

I followed http://blog.narenarya.in/right-way-django-authentication.html in order to add a user authentication in my Django project but when I run it and go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/log it shows page not found404! the others applications still working normally 
newsite/settings.py

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = 'k$1@+(lwis6$1e73$&f3xzk##qfs%$zv#=5n^st+05)zk%*@8@'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'aps',
'mail',
'log',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'newsite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['templates'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'newsite.wsgi.application'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR + '/media/'

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': '/home/hanou/Bureau/malouka/db.sqlite3',  
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'MOTDEPASSE',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                     
    'PORT': '',
}
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
},
{
    'NAME':   'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
},
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr-fr'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Paris'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
BASE_DIR + '/static/',
)
EMAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT=587
EMAIL_HOST_USER='*********@gmail.com'  
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='*********'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

newsite/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from aps import views
from mail import views
from log import views
from django.contrib.auth import views
from log.forms import LoginForm

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),    
url(r'^aps/', include('aps.urls')),
url(r'^mail/', include('mail.urls')),
url(r'^log/', include('log.urls')),
url(r'^login/$',views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html', 'authentication_form': LoginForm}),
url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, {'next_page': '/login'}),
]
```

newsite/log/views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(login_url="login/")
def home(request):
    return render(request,"home.html")
```

newsite/log/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

Comment: Can you show us log.urls?

Comment: How about `http://127.0.0.1:8000/log/`? Also, what is inside `log/urls.py`?

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/log/` (note the slash at the end and in the URL config)

Comment: it's  the same result ! I tried it at the begining

Comment: What is the url you get redirected to that throws the 404 ?

Comment: can we see log/urls.py

Comment: It doesn't make sense to do `from xxx import views` four times. Each time you do it, it replaces the previous views you imported. Since all you include is `views.login` and `views.logout`, you can remove all of those imports except  `from django.contrib.auth import views`. If you needed more than one views module you would do something like `from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views`

Comment: @alecxe an Georgina I added log/urls.py to the question.

Comment: @karthikr http://127.0.0.1:8000/log/login/?next=/log/

Comment: @Alasdair i changed in urls as you said but same result

Comment: The changes I suggested in the comment won't solve your 404 error, but it's a good idea to fix it anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your login_url is missing a leading slash. That means that you will redirected from `/log/` to `/log/login/`, which will give a 404.

You can fix it by changing it to:

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def home(request):
```

It works in the tutorial because they used

```
url(r'', include('log.urls')),
```

instead of

```
url(r'^log/', include('log.urls')),
```

However, I wouldn't recommend using relative urls like this. It's much better to use the absolute url with the slash, or even better, to [reverse the url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls) instead of hardcoding it.

To fix the `NoReverseMatch` error on the login page, change the form tag of the template to:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
```

and add the name to the login url pattern.

```
url(r'^login/$',views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html', 'authentication_form': LoginForm}, name='login'),
```

I would also add `LOGIN_URL` to your settings,

```
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
```

and then you won't have to specify it each time you use `login_required`.

```
@login_required
def home(request):
```

Comment: oh I haven't pay it attention . But I changed the server goes automaticaly to http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/?next=/log/ and as a result it says NoReverseMatch at /login/

Comment: That's a separate issue in the login template. See my updated answer.

Comment: thank you so much!! I tried it now and itt worked :)